# Change text in Column Chooser - ejs-grid

Tags: grid, ejs, column-chooser

I am using ejs-grid column chooser. I want to change the text 'Columns' to 'Show Column Chooser'. Is there any way I can do it without adding any external button as a solution.
[image: Ejs-grid]